# MongoDb findOneAndUpdate does not update specific document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having trouble getting and updating the only document that matches filter in nest array of objects in mongoose, I'm using the findOneAndUpdate query in mongoose.

This is my data:

```
{
  "_id": "62e87e193fe01f5068f9ae11",
  "year": "2023",
  "month": "1",
  "department_id":"62e387d39ffb6ada6c590fbf",
  "blocks": [
    {
      "name": "CEEDO Schedule Block",
      "days": [
        {
          "day": 2,
          "employees": [
            {
              "employee_id":"62cf92fb3a790000170062e3",
              "schedule_type": "Day Off"
            },
            {
              "employee_id": "62cf92fb3a790000170062e2",
              "schedule_type": "Shifting"
            },
            {
              "employee_id": "62cf92fb3a790000170062e4",
              "schedule_type": "Regular"
            }
          ],
          "_id": "62e87e193fe01f5068f9ae13"
        },
        {
          "day": 6,
          "employees": [
            {
              "employee_id": "62cf92fb3a790000170062e3",
              "schedule_type": "Day Off"
            },
            {
              "employee_id": "62cf92fb3a790000170062e2",
              "schedule_type": "Shifting"
            },
            {
              "employee_id":"62cf92fb3a790000170062e4",
              "schedule_type": "Regular"
            }
          ],
          "_id": "62e87e193fe01f5068f9ae14"
        }
      ],
      "_id": "62e87e193fe01f5068f9ae12"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is my query:

```
const update_block = await schedule_model.findOneAndUpdate({'blocks.days._id': '62e87e193fe01f5068f9ae13'}, 
    {
        $set: {"days":req.body.days, "employees":req.body.employees}
    }
    );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is result of ```console.log(update_block)```?

Comment: {
  _id: new ObjectId("62e87e193fe01f5068f9ae11"),
  year: '2023',
  month: '1',
  department_id: new ObjectId("62e387d39ffb6ada6c590fbf"),
  blocks: [
    {
      name: 'CEEDO Schedule Block',
      days: [Array],
      _id: new ObjectId("62e87e193fe01f5068f9ae12")
    },
    {
      name: 'CEEDO 2',
      days: [Array],
      _id: new ObjectId("62e89fa33fe01f5068f9b4d6")
    }
  ],
  __v: 0
} update_block

Comment: does not update the document

Answer (score 0):

try change `'62e87e193fe01f5068f9ae13'` to `mongoose.Types.ObjectId('62e87e193fe01f5068f9ae13')`

Comment: Same it does not work, i updated my code into


const update_block = await schedule_model.findOneAndUpdate({'blocks.days._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId('62e87e193fe01f5068f9ae14')}, 
    {
        $set: {"blocks.$.days.$.day":20}
    });

Comment: the result was: Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path 'blocks.$.days.$.day'

Comment: but if i will replace $ to 0 it will update the first element in array but not the exact object in array

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer by using the arrayFilter function in mongoose:

```
const update_block = await schedule_model.updateOne({
        "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId('62e87e193fe01f5068f9ae11')
    }, {
        "$set": {
            "blocks.$[i].days.$[j].day": 31
        }
    }, {
        arrayFilters: [{
            "i._id":mongoose.Types.ObjectId('62e87e193fe01f5068f9ae12')
        }, {
            "j._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId('62e87e193fe01f5068f9ae14')
        }]
    })

    console.log(update_block)
```

Thank you.